# What is the difference between using a "<=" sign instead of a "<" sign in the compare function of an STL in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

I have to implement the 3rd parameter, cmp, in the sort() function for sorting an **array of integers** **in descending order**.

The problem is that this definition doesn't work properly,

```
bool cmp (int a, int b)
{
    if(a<b)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

However, this does

```
bool cmp (int a, int b)
{
    if(a<=b)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

In the main() function, I use

```
sort(Arr,Arr+n,cmp);
```

Please note that I claim that the first code doesn't work properly because my solution to a problem on Codechef is accepted when I use the 2nd, but not with the 1st.

Comment: That can be used too, but I wanted to find out what the mistake in the present one was.

Comment: [The requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) are very clear.

Comment: The requirement violation becomes clearer if you simplify to `return a >= b;` and `return a > b;` The first one states that every number should be sorted before itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An STL compare function must return false if both values are equal.

Answer (score 2):

In [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort),

Last argument:

> comp  -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare))
>   ....

[Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare)

> comp(a, b)
>
> Establishes strict weak ordering relation with the following properties:
>
> **For all a, comp(a,a)==false**
>
> ....

That's why

```
if(a<=b) 
    return false;
```

works, while

```
if(a<b)
    return false;
```

doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`std::sort`'s compare function returns a value that indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific **strict weak ordering** it defines.

Here is the definition of strict weak ordering from [sgi](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html)

> A Strict Weak Ordering is a binary predicate that compares two
> objects, returning true if the first precedes the second. This
> predicate must satisfy the standard mathematical definition of a
> strict weak ordering. The precise requirements are stated below, but what
> they roughly mean is that a Strict Weak Ordering has to behave the way
> that "less than" behaves:
>
> - if a is less than b then b is not less than a,
> - if a is less than b and b is less than c then a is less than c,
>   and so on.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) of Compare functions:

> Establishes strict weak ordering relation

So, the function `comp` must define a strict weak ordering. By definition, it must satisfy three conditions:

1) `comp(x, x)` is false for all `x` (irreflexivity condition)

2) If `comp(x, y)` then `!comp(x, y)` (asymmetry condition)

3) If `comp(x, y)` and `comp(y, z)` then `comp(x, z)` (transitivity condition)

It is easy to see that first example of `cmp` function does not satisfy the irreflexivity condition, therefore it cannot be used to be passed as `comp` argument of `std::sort`. It is also clear that second `cmp` example in case of `x, y` are numbers satisfies all of three conditions, so it can be passed as `comp` argument to std::sort.

Answer (score 0):

The compare function provided to `std::sort` must return true if its first argument lies before its second argument in the ordering required and false otherwise.

Hence, for **descending** ordering you should use the `>` operator>, which for `int`s returns the complement of what the `<=` operator returns (which you used to implement your comparison with). Better use `std::greater<int>` to avoid such pitfalls.